# jQuery: How to remove a tr tag in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to delete a tr tag after clicking delete button using jQuery but it is not working, I used remove method of jQuery.
This is HTML code

```
<tbody>
<tr class="image-col"  th:each="image : ${session.galleryList}">
    <td><div class="col-sm-4 proj_gallery_grid section_1_gallery_grid">
                <div class="section_1_gallery_grid1">
                    <img th:src="@{'/images/' + ${image.imageURL}}" alt=" " class="img-fluid" />
                </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td th:text="${image.title}"></td>
    <td>
    <i style="display: none;" class="image-id" th:text="${image.id}"></i>
    <button class="delete-image-btn btn btn-success btn-block">Delete Image</button></td>
</tr>
```

And this is jQuery code.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-image-btn', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (confirm("Are youe sure to delete this image?")) {

        var message = "Image deleted successfully";
        var imageId = $(this).parent().find(".image-id").text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/image/delete_image?imid=" + imageId,
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.status) {
                    $(this).parent().find('.image-col').remove();
                } else {
                    alert(result.message);
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error! Please try again");
            }
        });
        return;
    } else {
        return;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `_t.parent().parent().remove();`

```js
   $(document).on('click', '.delete-image-btn', function(){
   var _t = $(this);
  
   // event.preventDefault();
    if(confirm("Are youe sure to delete this image?")){
    
    _t.parent().parent().remove(); 

        var message = "Image deleted successfully";
        var imageId = $(this).parent().find(".image-id").text();
        
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
<tr class="image-col"  th:each="image : ${session.galleryList}">
    <td><div class="col-sm-4 proj_gallery_grid section_1_gallery_grid">
                <div class="section_1_gallery_grid1">
                    <img th:src="@{'/images/' + ${image.imageURL}}" alt=" " class="img-fluid" />
                </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td th:text="${image.title}"></td>
    <td>
      <i style="display: none;" class="image-id" th:text="${image.id}"></i>
      <button class="delete-image-btn btn btn-success ">Delete Image</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks Devsi Odedra it is working...May I know how this code is working _t.parent().parent().remove();

Comment: I know because it happen with me once, but also `closest()` must work as per doc but it is not working, I dont know the extact reason but with parent().parent(). find a parent tr and thats why it's working.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
$('.delete-image-btn').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
})
```

Comment: Not giving output with this solution also sir.

Answer (score 0):

Your DOM search for `tr` with `class` is wrong. Parent of your button is `td` not `tr`. So to remove `tr` you can use `closest` to find `tr` and remove.

```
$(this).closest("tr").remove();
```

Like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-image-btn', function(event) {
 var $this = $(this); // Hold your this state before ajax call
```

After that :

```
$this.closest("tr").remove();
```

Comment: Shree thanks from your answer but still its not working

Comment: You can check in console using `$(this).closest("tr").length`. And let me know what you get.

Comment: And also check what `result.status` return ??

Comment: I checked result status control is coming inside if statement.

Comment: $(this).closest("tr").length is giving output 0